# Is there a celebration in a plane when crossing the Equator line?

Tags: air-travel, factoids

I recently read that in the old days (early 60s) the planes that crossed the Equator line would do some celebration when this happened. Cabin crew would give some pastries, and even liquors, to the passengers.

Is this still common in commercial flights?

While researching I found information about the [Line-crossing ceremony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-crossing_ceremony), but this is *an initiation rite (...) that commemorate a sailor's first crossing of the Equator*.

Comment: Early 60s.. no in-flight entertainment systems, people needed to do something to entertain themselves.

Comment: Sadly the legend that a certain buggy version of the F-14 software caused the plane to roll upside down in "celebration" of being in the southern hemisphere, is probably a myth.

Comment: @SteveJessop the F-22 had a systems issue when it crossed the international date line on its way to its first overseas deployment in Japan... they had to be escorted back to Hawaii by their tankers, where their systems were updated and the flights were resumed 48 hours later.

Comment: On a number of long flights that cross the equator, passengers are likely to be sleeping at this time. A big celebration or even an announcement would not be amusing to someone trying to sleep.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertropical_Convergence_Zone "Thunderstorms along the Intertropical Convergence Zone played a role in the loss of Air France Flight 447"

Comment: @Moo and to think my bosses ask why my databases always use UTC...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have been on flights a couple of times where the pilot made an announcement, but nothing more than that.  Flying across the Equator in this day and age is a non-event, same as flying over the International Date Line or the Arctic Circle.

While it might be cool to someone who doesn't travel much, it is not unique enough to warrant a celebration (especially not free booze ;-).  Back in the day, when planes didn't go as far and you had to hop from airstrip to airstrip refueling to reach Australia from Los Angeles, it was a big deal.  But today planes do it in a single flight and the Equator is crisscrossed by a multitude of flights every day.

Comment: Indeed! In the book I am reading, the guy describes a New York -> Buenos Aires flight that took 18 hours, stopping in Washington, Miami, Panama, Lima, Santiago de Chile and Buenos Aires.

Comment: As an Aussie, I'd find it particularly exciting to fly over the Arctic Circle, but as for the Equator, I fly across that pretty much whenever I leave Australia :P

Comment: I first crossed the Equator on a flight from Singapore (1 deg N) to Jakarta (a few deg S), in a plane full of business passengers. I'm fairly sure I was the only person on the plane excited by the event!

Comment: I've crossed it many times and not even once had anyone mention it. I always kept a look out though, hoping to see that big dotted-line in the sky.

Comment: @Lyall however, there is such a thing when you cross the Meridian nearby Barcelona! See this post in Spanish at least for the pictures: http://www.microsiervos.com/archivo/mundoreal/meridiano-greenwich.html

Comment: @Lyall you're looking the wrong direction - it's floating across the ocean ;)

Comment: 'The equator is crisscrossed by a multitude of flights every day' - to give this some scale, you can see just how many planes are crossing every few minutes here: https://www.flightradar24.com/-4.96,-1.08/3

Comment: *"While it might be cool to someone who doesn't travel much"*... it's not really a matter of how much you travel rather than where you travel, right? You could travel all over the place in America, Europe, and Asia without ever crossing the equator... and I get the feeling that people who are from the northern hemisphere generally don't end up going to the southern hemisphere much, even very frequent travelers.

Comment: Over the 30 or so times I have flown over the equator I have never heard an announcement that we have done so... If you want to have your own personal celebration turn on the flight tracker and wait for that precious moment. However most of the pacific flights are flown overnight likely to happen when the lights are dimmed and sleep is attempted.

Comment: @Mehrdad - when you consider that almost 70% of the land mass and more than 80% of the population is in the northern hemisphere, it stands to reason folks from the north don't go south that much and folks from the south go north frequently.

Answer (score 7):

On a KLM flight from Buenos Aires to Amsterdam in January 2015 they performed an "equatorial baptism" - this is when a crew member is crossing the equator for the first time and a ceremony is performed.

I can't remember exactly what they did (it was a large plane so I couldn't see what was going on for most of it) but the captain dressed up as Neptune (with a wig and plastic trident) and marched down to the rear of the plane with the crew member being "baptised" and some other members of the crew.

After doing the ceremony near the back of the plane they returned back to the cabin.

Comment: Funny, someone dressed as Neptune pouring water on others is something I have seen as an "arctic circle baptism" ceremony.

Comment: Wouldn't one expect KLM crew to be based in Amsterdam, so the crew member in question would have already crossed the equator on the _outbound_ flight?

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, I received a certificate from KLM when I crossed the equator in 1965.

It is in Dutch and it reads:

> Bij deze verklaren wij, dat Jacobus Bernardus Augustinus Korten, per vliegtuig PH-DCE Thomas Alva Edison van de Koninklijke Luchtvaart Maatschappij op 9 April 1965 de evenaar heeft gepasseerd.

Translation:

> We hereby state that Jacobus Bernardus Augustinus Korten, by plane PH-DCE Thomas Alva Edison of the Dutch Royal Airline, has passed the equator on 9 April 1965.

Comment: Oh, that's a beautiful document to have!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, **no**. Source: lots of own trips crossing it.

That might be the case of ships though. But how many people is still crossing the Equator line in a ship? Not many.

Comment: [Plenty of ships do](http://www.marinetraffic.com)

Comment: @neo:  [much fewer than before.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_liner)

Comment: @QuoraFeans But your comment implied that *nobody* is doing it, hence neos comment.

Comment: I would dare say the number of ships crossing has not decreased that much, as a vast amount of freight, crude oil, etc still travels by sea and the number of cruise ships vastly outnumbers what was around in the past.

Comment: As tourists in ships? Relatively few. As freight crew? Loads!

Comment: @Tom: I would dare to say that you are right. I suppose there are many more private sail ships nowadays than 50 years ago.

Comment: Fair comments but the size of the crew on modern freighters is very small so that's still not that many people.

Answer (score 2):

Going from Ecuador to Panama on 1972, KLM gave me a button that said " I crossed the Equator with KLM Royal Dutch airline."

Comment: Oh, so beautiful. Would it be possible to see it? You can upload an image into your post. This is 50 years ago, but maybe you still keep it... :)